# Помогите вьехать в тесты, не понимаю что надо тестировать

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, testng, xunit

Разобрался что такое моки и стабы(со стабами сложнее)
Хотел написать тесты для своего проекта, но не могу понять что тут тестировать?
Вот пример интерфейса:

```
/// <summary>
/// RU
/// Интерфейс отвечает за вызов метода провайдера базы данных для записи в бд
/// EN
/// The interface is responsible for calling the database provider method to write to the database
/// </summary>
namespace DBWorkerService.Services
{
    public interface IStorageWorker
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// RU
        /// В зависимости от ключа["Action"] в массиве, вызывает нужную процедуру базы данных
        /// EN
        /// Depending on the [Action] key in the array, it calls the required database procedure
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="transaction">
        /// RU
        /// Массив представляющий набор данных вида ключ/значение
        /// EN
        /// An array representing a data set of the type key / value
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// RU
        /// Количество строк затронутых в процессе записи
        /// EN
        /// Number of rows affected during the write process
        /// </returns>
        int Write( Dictionary<string, string>[] transaction );
    }
}
```

Вот реализация:

```
public int Write( Dictionary<string, string>[] transaction )
{
    int numberOfRowsProcessed = 0;
    try
    {
        int countTransaction = transaction?.Length ?? 0;

        for ( int i = 0; i < countTransaction; i++ )
        {
            switch ( transaction[ i ][ "Action" ] )
            {
                case "create":
                    numberOfRowsProcessed += dbProvider.Execute( transaction[ i ], ( int )ProcedureName.Create );
                    break;
                case "edit":
                    numberOfRowsProcessed += dbProvider.Execute( transaction[ i ], ( int )ProcedureName.Update );
                    break;
                case "delete":
                    numberOfRowsProcessed += dbProvider.Execute( transaction[ i ], ( int )ProcedureName.Delete );
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return numberOfRowsProcessed;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        logger.LogError( e, $"[{nameof( StorageWorker )}] An error occurred while working with the storage. Details: {e.Message}" );
        return numberOfRowsProcessed;
    };
}
```

Я вообще не въезжаю как ту и что можно оттестировать?

Comment: У вас есть какая то функция, так? В этой функции есть какой то код. Код что то делает. У кода на входе есть параметры функции. На выходе возвращаемое значение. Так вот вам надо вызывать эту функцию, передавать параметры и проверять, что выходное значение соответствует логике функции и переданным параметрам.

Comment: а если на выходе void?

Comment: Если функция ничего не возвращает, значит она меняет состояние переданных в неё объектов или переданных параметров конструктора класса объектов, или имеет какие-либо другие побочные эффекты (например, остановка потока или запись в файл или ещё что то), вот это и надо проверять. Если же функция ничего не делает, то значит кода в ней нет, как и логики,  то есть она пустая - тогда, тестить там нечего.

Comment: @tym32167 все становится на свои места спасибо

Comment: @tym32167, автор вопроса забыл упомянуть ваш ник. Соответственно, вам бы не пришло уведомление. Вот я и исправил упущение, заодно указав, что это не к вам обращаюсь, а призвал к сообщению выше (циркумфлекс — это как бы стрелочка вверх).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основной посыл в том, что каждая написанная функция должна иметь причину - для чего она написана. То есть тот, кто решил написать функцию, хотел этой функцией что то достичь. Формально это можно выразить так:

1. Перед запуском функции должны быть соблюдены некоторые условия (это требования к параметрам на входе функции, это требования к состоянию объекта функции, это требования к переданным аругементам класса, где находится фунция, и все такое прочее). Эти условия в общем случае называются *предусловиями*. То есть перед тем, как функция может быть вызвана, должны быть соблюдены предусловия для функции. Например, у функции int Calculator.Div(int a, int b), есть предусловие, что b!=0.
2. После вызова функции также должны быть соблюдены какие то условия. Как пример, функция 
   TimeService.GetToday() ни при каких условиях не должна вернуть NULL. То есть это такие условия, которые гарантируют, что функция в принципе отработала. Может и некорректно, то отработала. Это называется *постусловием*.
3. Далее, функция что то должна делать. Это что то - может быть подсчетом какого то результата, получением откуда-то данных или их запись, или что либо ещё. По сути я бы разделил результат работы функции на 2 типа - это возращаемое значение и побочные эффекты. Например, если функция не имеет побочных эффектов, то есть она оперирует только теми объектами, что были переданы как параметры функции (причем она не изменяет их состояние), то функия называется *чистой*. Как пример - int Calculator.Sum(int x, int y) - чистая функция.

Отмечу, что совокупность предусловий и постусловаий также называется *контрактом* функции.  Итак, перед тем, как писать новую функцию, программист должен знать предусловия, постусловия, и, собственно, что функция должна делать. Что тут тестировать? Юнит тест обычно состоит из 3 частей - так называемые AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert). Arrange - это подготовка поедусловий для функции. Act - это собственно вызов функции и фиксация результата функции. Assert - это проверка постусловий + проверка логики функции.

Рассмотрим абстрактный пример теста int Calculator.Div(int a, int b)

1. Arrange - состоит в подготовке предусловий. Предусловия для int Calculator.Div(int a, int b) по сути это - наличие 2 целочисленных параметров и также второй параметр не может быть равен 0.
2. Act - просто вызов и фиксация результата
3. Assert - проверка постусловий (которых нет), и корректности. Код мог вы выглядеть так:

пример:

```
int i=10, j=5; // arrange
var result = Calculator.Div(i, j); // act
Assert.Equals(/*expected value*/ 2 , /*actual value*/ result); // assert
```

Теперь мы знаем о предусловаиях, постусловиях, и о том, как тестировать функцию. Дальнейшая терминология уже может пойти проще. Например, если программист проверяет предусловия и постусловия прямо в коде функции (то есть проверяет соответсвие контракту функции), то это называется контрактым программированием. Или если программист сначала пишет тесты для функий, а уже потом сами функции - то это будет TDD (Test Driven Development, можно перевести как разработка, управляемая тестами)

Comment: Еще раз хотел поблагодарить вас за развернутый ответ, и задать еще один вопрос. Вы не знаете где можно посмотреть эталонные проекты с тестами, что бы иметь представление как это происходит в жизни. Желательно на C#

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov эталонных проектов с тестами в природе нет. Все подбирается индивидуально - и объем тестирования, и что конкретно тестить, и фреймворки. Чтобы писать легко тестируемый код или хорошие тесты, надо изучать теорию и много практиковаться. Лично мне помогли [книги Фаулера](https://martinfowler.com/books/), [Бека](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Test-Driven-Development-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321146530) и [Роберта Мартина](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=BDMFY7N8F6SZ3TM2Y3N4).

Comment: подскажите, а надо тестировать приватные методы объекта?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov разные разработчики считают по разному. Кто то тестирует приватные. Кто то делает методы internal, а сборку с тестами дружественную, чтобы иметь доступ к методам напрямую и тестить их. Я считаю, что в основном надо тестировать только публичные методы класса, которые и определяют его поведение. То есть если есть какой то большой приватный метод со сложной логикой -то его можно вынести в отдельный класс, который будет заниматься только этой логикой, и метод сделать с нем публичным. Но иногда мне лень выносить метод в класс, и я просто делаю его internal, хоть это и не по правилам